# Restore PATH after accidental erasure

Tags: bash

I did something VERY stupid. When playing with variables in the terminal, I did `NAME=whatever` and then decided to try a path so then without thinking I named the variable appropriately: `PATH='.'`

SO THAT WAS A BAD THING TO DO.

Almost zero commands are working, and after everything it says `sed: command not found`.

Oh my goodness, **please** tell me there's some way to get my old path back.

A few various files that expand on the path are intact:

#### ~/.profile

```sh
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/.yarn-global/bin:$PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

#### ~/.bash_profile

in various places in the file:

```sh
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
export USR_PATHS="/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:$ANDROID_PATH"
export PATH="$USR_PATHS:$PATH"
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$
```

After running `source ~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.profile` a few errors are gone but most things still don't work:

```
$ code .
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you just close and reopen your shell?

Comment: reboot to the rescue! :)

Comment: Sigh. Yes. I can just reopen my shell. Thank you.

Comment: This is why you don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for your shell variables. Some of them are already in use by the system and the shell itself.

Comment: `source /etc/environment; source ~/.profile`

Comment: As you have just discovered, environment variables are inherently local. They only exist within a process (and can be inherited by child processes, etc). Changing the environment of a running shell has no permanent effects; exiting from the shell wipes out everything.

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is enough:

```
. /etc/environment
```

Optionally also re-import `.profile`

```
. ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by some of the comments, the change I made was only local to the current shell. Opening a new shell reverted the environment.